# How do "chameleon particles" conserve energy and momentum?

Tags: energy-conservation, conservation-laws, dark-energy

I recently learned about the [Chameleon particle](https://home.cern/news/news/physics/kwisp-detector-searches-dark-energy-sun) model for dark energy, which involves bosonic particles whose mass changes depending on the nearby matter concentration, such that their mediated force has a very short range in high-density regions and long range in low-density regions.

Now, as long as we're talking about virtual particles as a model for the behavior of a non-excited field, I have no problem with that. But if you consider free particles, there seems to be problem--for their mass to change as they travel through different regions of space, their velocity would have to change as well in order to conserve energy--but that can't be done in a frame-invariant manner, and it alters their momentum by a different factor!

So, how does it work? How can chameleons change mass in flight without violating conservation laws?

Comment: I don’t see why there would be a problem. For the chameleon effect to happen, there needs to be an interaction with matter. Interactions cost energy.